# Macbook Pro 2010 with Maverick restarting

Tags: macbook-pro

I have read tones of advice on this and I still have no solution and just wanted some personal advice.

My macbook pro mid 2010 keeps restarting randomly, not always on the same program.

It works fine in safe mode.

I just wondered if anyone had any advice on how to stop this happening, I've tried uni stalling certain programs, deleting files, everything I can think of.

Please can some help me :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What MacBook Pro model exactly?

Answer (score 1):

My one experience years ago with this was 15" Powerbook ... but Apple Support told me that was a sign the motherboard was going, and they replaced it (on Applecare)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was fault NVIDIA GPU (MacBook Pro mid-2010 15-inch). I had to replace GPU chipset. Maybe this is the same case. Do you have a diagnostic report window after restart with KernelPanic exception or GPUPanic ?

Comment: Hi @Pawel Urban, I have this kernel panic report: "@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.9/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127" I also own a MacBook Pro mid-2010 15-inch. Same problem than you? It seems!